# Chat Application Using PHP updating previous messages

Tags: php, html, ajax, chatbot, aiml

Why this code not working

I am building a chatbot application using php and aiml. I have made the chat window for the same. But in chat window when I enter the message it overwrites the previous message every time. I want that the new message should come in the new line. Please help

My Code is

```
<div class="panel" id="chat">
<div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:#337ab7">
  <h3 class="panel-title" style="color:#FFF">
    <i class="icon wb-chat-text" aria-hidden="true" ></i> How Can I Help You
  </h3>
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
  <div class="chats">
    <div class="chat">
      <div class="chat-avatar">
        <a class="avatar avatar-online" data-toggle="tooltip" href="#" data-placement="right" title="" data-original-title="June Lane">
          <i></i>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="chat-body">
        <div class="chat-content">
          <p>
            <div class="botsay">Hey!</div>
          </p>
          <time class="chat-time" datetime="2015-07-01T11:37">
          <?php
                echo date("h:i:sa");
            ?></time>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="chat chat-left">
      <div class="chat-avatar">
        <a class="avatar avatar-online" data-toggle="tooltip" href="#" data-placement="left" title="" data-original-title="Edward Fletcher">

          <i></i>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="chat-body">
        <div class="chat-content">
          <p><div class="usersay">&nbsp;</div></p>
           <time class="chat-time" datetime="2015-07-01T11:37">
          <?php
                echo date("h:i:sa");
            ?></time>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel-footer">

  <form method="post" name="talkform" id="talkform" action="index.php">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="say" >
      <input type="hidden" name="convo_id" id="convo_id" value="<?php echo $convo_id;?>" />
      <input type="hidden" name="bot_id" id="bot_id" value="<?php echo $bot_id;?>" />
      <input type="hidden" name="format" id="format" value="json" />
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <input class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="submit" id="submit"  value="Send" />
      </span>

    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

I am using ajax to input values in the chat window using aiml.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // put all your jQuery goodness in here.
    $('#talkform').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var user = $('#say').val();
      $('.usersay').text(user);
      var formdata = $("#talkform").serialize();
      $('#say').val('');
      $('#say').focus();
      $.get('<?php echo $url ?>', formdata, function(data){
        var b = data.botsay;
        if (b.indexOf('[img]') >= 0) {
          b = showImg(b);
        }
        if (b.indexOf('[link') >= 0) {
          b = makeLink(b);
        }
        var usersay = data.usersay;
        if (user != usersay) {
          $('.usersay').text(usersay);
        }
        $('.botsay').html(b);
      }, 'json').fail(function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
        $('#urlwarning').html("Something went wrong! Error = " + errorThrown);
      });
      return false;
    });
  });
  function showImg(input) {
    var regEx = /\[img\](.*?)\[\/img\]/;
    var repl = '<br><a href="$1" target="_blank"><img src="$1" alt="$1" width="150" /></a>';
    var out = input.replace(regEx, repl);
    console.log('out = ' + out);
    return out
  }
  function makeLink(input) {
    var regEx = /\[link=(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/link\]/;
    var repl = '<a href="$1" target="_blank">$2</a>';
    var out = input.replace(regEx, repl);
    console.log('out = ' + out);
    return out;
  }
```

[image]

Comment: Wow... AIML! You say AJAX, and there's not a single line of JavaScript? That's what is important. Where you are adding it.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Let me know if my answer works. If you edit the question, please ping people. At least comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is you are just keeping on replacing the contents of `usersay` and `botsay`. You need to append or prepend as per your need to make it work.

Consider this bit of code, you need to change as per comments:

```
  $.get('<?php echo $url ?>', formdata, function(data){
    var b = data.botsay;
    if (b.indexOf('[img]') >= 0) {
      b = showImg(b);
    }
    if (b.indexOf('[link') >= 0) {
      b = makeLink(b);
    }
    var usersay = data.usersay;
    if (user != usersay) {
      $('.usersay').append(usersay);    // 1. Change here.
    }
    $('.botsay').append(b);             // 2. Change here.
  }, 'json')
```

Comment: Ya the code is only adding the text in the previous chat. But I also want that each chat should come in new line. Can u help me out

Comment: @Prerana Yes, definitely. Can you provide a full working code example somewhere editable like http://C9.io

Comment: @Prerana Did you try using `<br />` at the end to get it to the next line? Try it and tell me?

Comment: I have tried <br/> but it is not working. Its coming on the same line as the previous chat.

Comment: @Prerana Any way to share the code and make it work somewhere live?

Comment: I have added the image with the question pls check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132559/discussion-between-prerana-and-praveen-kumar).